# Installing Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Im having trouble installing Apache Lucene.  The only guide I found was here:

```
http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/demo.html
```

After downloading the compressed file and extracted it, there should be a file called something like:
    lucene-core-{version}.jar

According to the instructions, but I can't find this.  Am I doing something stupid?  I am a java newbie so maybe the solution is simple.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of lucene is 4.6.0 and not 3.5.0.

So first look at the doc of the latest version:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/index.html

and in the wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/

if you want to run the demo as explained at http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description

Download the lucene-4.6.0.zip extract it onyou machine.
Setup your classpath with four JARs:

- the Lucene JAR,
- the queryparser JAR,
- the common analysis JAR,
- and the Lucene demo JAR.

Those jar are located inside the directory you created from lucene-4.6.0.zip in following subdirectories:

- the core/ directory (lucene-core-4.6.0.jar )
- queryparser,
- analysis/common/
- and demo

hth